# extern function during linkage?

Tags: c, linux

I have this weird thing:

in a file1.c there's

```
extern void foo(int x, int y);
..
..

int tmp = foo(1,2);
```

in the project I could find only this foo():

in file2.c :

```
int foo(int x, int y, int z)
{
....
}
```

in file2.h :

```
int foo(int x, int y, int z);
```

file2.h isn't included in file1.c (this is why who wrote it used extern, i guess).

this project compiles fine, I think that's because in file1.c foo() will be looked for only during linkage, am I right?

but my real question is : why is the linkage succssful ?
after all, there is no such function as foo with 2 parameters....
and i'm in c .. so there's no overloading..

so what's going on ?

Comment: The `extern` declaration is redundant if the header file is included.  But it does no harm.

Comment: the header file is NOT included

Comment: Then it's a poorly structured program, which is easy in C. It may be the author used the external as a temporary measure and forgot about it. Or it's a hack due to some conflict caused by including the whole header.

Answer (score 7):

Because there is no overloading, the C compiler does not decorate the function names. The linker finds in `file2.c` a reference to function `foo` and in `file1.c` it finds a function `foo`. It cannot know their parameter lists do not match and happily use them.

Of course, when the function `foo` runs the value of `z` is garbage and the behavior of the program becomes unpredictable from that point on.

Comment: but why, if i write :
    extern void foo(void);

and then use it :
foo(1,2,3);
then it doesn't pass compilation ?

Comment: @user1047069 Because the `extern void foo(void)` prototype and the call `foo(1,2,3)` are in the same source file. The compiler sees right away at the call that it doesn't match the prototype which says the function takes no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a function with the wrong number (or types) of arguments is an error.
The standard requires the implementation to detect some, but not all of them.

What the standard calls an implementation, is typically a compiler with a separate linker (and some other things), where a compiler translates single translation units (that is, a preprocessed source file) into object files, which later get linked together.
While the standard doesn't distinct between them, its authors of course wrote it with the typical setup in mind.

C11 (n1570) 6.5.2.2 "Function calls", p2:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that includes a prototype, the number of arguments shall agree with the number of parameters. Each argument shall have a type such that its value may be assigned to an object with the unqualified version of the type of its corresponding parameter.

This is in a "constraints" section, which means, the implementation (in this case, that's the compiler) must complain and may abort translation if a "shall" requirement is violated.

In your case, there was a prototype visible, so the arguments of the function call must match *with the prototype*.

Similar requirements apply for a function definition with a prototype declaration in scope; if your function definition doesn't match the prototype, your compiler must tell you. In other words, as long as you ensure that all calls to a function and that function's definition are in the scope of the same prototype, you are told if there is a mismatch. This can be ensured if the prototype is in a header file which is included by all files with calls to that function and by the file containing its definition. We use header files with prototypes exactly for that reason.

In the code shown, this checking is by-passed by providing a non-matching prototype and not including the header **file2.h**.

Ibid. p9:

> If the function is defined with a type that is not compatible with the type (of the expression) pointed to by the expression that denotes the called function, the behavior is undefined.

Undefined behaviour means, the compiler is free to assume it doesn't happen, and is not required to detect if it does.

And in fact, on my machine, the generated object files from **file2.c** (I inserted a `return 0;` to have some function body), don't differ if I remove one of the function arguments, which means, the object file doesn't contain any information about the arguments und thus a compiler seeing only **file2.o** and **file1.c** hasn't got any chance to detect the violation.

You've mentioned overloading, so let's compile **file2.c** (with two and three arguments) as C++ and look at the object files:

```
$ g++ file2_three_args.cpp -c
$ g++ file2_two_args.cpp -c
$ nm file2_three_args.o   
00000000 T _Z3fooiii
$ nm file2_two_args.o 
00000000 T _Z3fooii
```

Function `foo` has its arguments incorporated into the symbol created for it (a process called name mangling), the object file indeed carries some information about the function types. Accordingly, we get an error at link time:

```
$ cat file1.cpp
extern void foo(int x, int y);

int main(void) {
        foo(1,2);
}
$ g++ file2_three_args.o file1.cpp
In function `main':
file1.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `foo(int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This behaviour would also be allowed for a C implementation, aborting translation is a valid manifestation of undefined behaviour at compile or link time.

The way overloading in C++ is usually done actually *allows* such checks at link time. That C doesn't have built-in support for function overloading, and that the behaviour is undefined for the cases where the compiler cannot see the type mismatches, allows to generate symbols for functions without any type information.

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
extern void foo(int x, int y);
```

means exactly the same thing as

```
void foo(int x, int y);
```

The former is just an overly explicit way to write the same thing. `extern` fills no other purpose here. It is like writing `auto int x;` instead of `int x`, it means the very same thing.

---

In your case, the "foo" module (which you call file2) contains the function prototype as well as the definition. This is proper program design in C. What file1.c should be doing is to `#include` the foo.h.

For reasons unknown, whoever wrote file1.c didn't do this. Instead they are just saying "elsewhere in the project, there is this function, do not care about its definition, that's handled elsewhere".

***This is bad programming practice.*** file1.c shouldn't concern itself with how things are defined elsewhere: this is *spaghetti programming* which creates a needless tight coupling between the caller and the module. There is also the chance that the actual function doesn't match the local prototype, in which case you would hopefully get linker errors. But there are no guarantees.

The code must be fixed like this:

file1.c

```
#include "foo.h"
...
int tmp = foo(1,2);
```

foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

int foo(int x, int y, int z);

#endif
```

foo.c

```
#include "foo.h"

int foo(int x, int y, int z)
{
....
}
```