# extern function during linkage

Tags: c, linux

My question is a continuation of this one:
[extern function during linkage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144500/extern-function-during-linkage)

I now tried in file2.c:

```
extern int foo(void);
```

and I called

```
foo(1,2,3);
```

Now, I got a compilation error that there are too many arguments in 
    foo(1,2,3);

Why does that happen ? We just said that extern functions are looked for during linkage and that in that stage there's no consideration regarding the parameters...

Comment: Yes, you told compiler that foo() is an external function and also that its prototype is int foo(void). Enough for the compiler to check its parameters.

Comment: The whole purpose of the first statement is to declare the prototype of foo(). This is just the same as #include of the header file in which foo() is declared.

If you omit the first line, and call foo(1,2,3), the compilation process will end successfully, with a warning of implicit declaration.

Comment: In the original question there was also different number of parameters in file1.c and file2.c and it compiled and linked..
what's the difference ?

Answer (score 2):

> `extern` functions are looked for during linkage and that in that stage there's no consideration regarding the parameters.

That's exactly right. However, you get an error at the compiling stage, not at linkage stage. You promised the compiler that there is a function `foo` that takes no parameters, and then you call `foo` with three parameters. Compiler does not take that, and reports the error.

The problem with the linker disregarding parameters would be if you separately compiled `foo` with zero parameters and a call to `foo` with a non-matching prototype that takes three parameters. This is undefined behavior.

impl.c

```
void foo() {}
```

main.c

```
void foo(int,int,int);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    foo(1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

If you compile the above, it would link, because you tricked the compiler by giving it a wrong prototype, and the linker does not know any better.

Answer (score 0):

by saying `extern int foo(void);`, you're telling the compiler to look for the function definition at linking time. In this process, you're already supplying the function prototype [declaration] `int foo(void);`, where the number of parameter is 0.

But, while using , you're calling `foo(1,2,3);`, so the comilation error is happenning.

Note: If i'm not mistaken, function declarations are by default `extern`.